# get an error at compilation "attempted to call undefined method in my controller on my bundle"

Tags: php, symfony

hi everyone i try to resolve this:
 "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getUser" of class "recrutement\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert" " in my controller on my bundle

```
class AdvertController extends Controller
{
/**
   * Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
   */
  //security.token_storage
  public function addAction(Request $request)
  {
    $advert = new Advert();
    $form   = $this->get('form.factory')->create(AdvertType::class, $advert);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
      $event = new MessagePostEvent($advert->getContent(), $advert->getUser());//$advert->getUser()->getSession()
      $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(PlatformEvents::POST_MESSAGE, $event); 
      $advert->setContent($event->getMessage());
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($advert);
      $em->flush();
      $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');
      return $this->redirectToRoute('recrutement_platform_view', array('id' => $advert->getId()));
    }
    return $this->render('recrutementPlatformBundle:Advert:add.html.twig', array(
      'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: emm.. any code you want to share with us?

Comment: some context, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to the Getter and Setter in recrutement\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert for $user.